# Ramsey-Turán density function is well defined

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Define
$$RT(n,K_l,f(n))=ex_l(n,f(n))=\max_G\{e(G): K_l \not\subset G, v(G)=n, \alpha(G)\leq f(n)\}$$
and the Ramsey-Turán density function $f_l:(0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f_l(\alpha)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{ex_l(n,\alpha n)}{{n\choose 2}}.$$

By Turán Theorem we have that $f_l(\alpha)=1-\frac{1}{l-1}$ for every $\alpha \geq \frac{1}{l-1}$.

How to prove that this limit exists for every $\alpha \in (0,1]$?

I was trying to prove that the sequence $(ex_l(n,\alpha n)/{n\choose 2})_n$ is monotone, but I could only prove that
$$ex_l(n,s)\leq\frac{n \ ex_l(n-1,s)}{n-2},$$
which is not enough since $ex_l(n-1,\alpha n) \geq ex_l(n-1,\alpha(n-1)).$

I also thought of using that $\alpha(G) \leq \alpha n$ and $\alpha(G)\leq \alpha(n-1)$ only give different restrictions once every $\approx 1/\alpha$ values of $n$ in a row. But it would also be necessary to show that every jump is in the same direction, which I couldn't do.

**Edit 1:** In [Simonovits and Sós](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Ramsey-Tur%C3%A1n-theory-Simonovits-S%C3%B3s/b6acab1b394d5096f2cd7221022553cc2cad2f7d) survey on Ramsey-Turán theory, when defining $RT(n,L^{(r)},s)$ for $r$-uniform hypergraphs, they say that the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{RT(n,L^{(r)},\varepsilon n)}{n^r}$$
exists and follows relatively easily from vertex-multiplication. I don't quite know how vertex-multiplication works but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the question in detail for $RT(n, K_l, \alpha n)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4282372/383078) on Math StackExchange.

Comment: Just for the record, this is the same as my answer from two weeks earlier, except that it provides all the straightforward details of the Fekete lemma type argument.

Comment: This is probably the difference between MO and MSE. (When writing my answer, I figured that to the MSE audience, those details would not be particularly straightforward.)

Comment: @domotorp As you said in a comment before, this Fekete lemma type argument didn't seem to be trivial. I agree the main idea of the proof was provided by you first, but it seems better for future reference to put the most complete answer as right.

Answer (score 5):

New Answer: It indeed follows from vertex-multiplication. If you replace each vertex with a stable set of size $k$, then $\alpha(G)/n$ will not change, while $n^r$ and the number of edges both grow by a $k^r$ factor. This shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{RT(n,L^{(r)},\varepsilon n)}{n^r}$ has a limit by a [Fekete lemma](http://%7B8bedebf1-18fb-4e33-88c9-c9a4c58134a5%7D) type argument.

Old Answer: Many of these functions are not known to have a limit. In this case when someone proves a bound on them, in fact they show a bound for the liminf or limsup. Unfortunately, in many papers they refer to it as lim, which also bothers me a lot. Incidentally, I've just asked the same thing two weeks ago (about the uniform Turan density function) from Danial Kral'.

Comment: I believe that in this case it would be quite surprising if it is just a definition problem.

[Lüders, Reiher (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03352) say it is well known and easy to confirm that this limit exists.
[Łuczak, Polcyn, Reiher (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.11474) also say that this limit exists, referring to [Erdos, Hajnal, Sós, Szemerédi (1983)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579342), but I couldn't find it there.

Comment: @JPM You are right, this follows from vertex-multiplication.

Comment: Can you explain this idea a little bit better? Are you deleting the edge and adding vertices?

Comment: @JPM No, just blowing up vertices. For example, if your graph is just a $K_2$, the edge $uv$, then if $k=2$, the new graph becomes a $C_4$, $v_1u_1v_2u_2$.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! One more thing, for cliques it is clear that this new blow-up graph will be $K_l$-free. How is this true for a general graph? For example, $K_{2,2,2} \not \subset K_3$, but applying your idea in $K_3$ with $k \geq 2$ would imply that our new graph has a $K_{2,2,2}.$

Comment: Why do you think that it holds for general graphs?

Comment: This $L^{(r)}$ in Simonovits and Sós survey is a general $r$-uniform hypergraph.

Comment: It is also not completely clear on how to finish it. This proves that $ex_l(n,\alpha n) \leq k^2ex_l(kn, \alpha (kn))$ for every $k$ and $n$. That is, 
$$\frac{ex_l(n,\alpha n)}{n^2}\leq \frac{ex_l(nk,\alpha (nk))}{(nk)^2}.$$
But how to finish with it? Exactly the Fekete Lemma doesn't seem to fit.
Is it true that any limited sequence $(a_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying $a_{n} \leq a_{nk}$ for every $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ converges?

Comment: @JPM No, that's not true for any sequence. Here we should use that the sequence $a_n$ is almost continuous, so something like $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ are not far, though even this does not seem to be trivial to prove, I'm positive this approach works. Regarding $L^{(r)}$, I don't see what to do.